# android AllertDialog doesn't have margin - What can cause this? maybe style issue?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, appcompatactivity

I want to show an [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) in the onCreate function of my [AppCompatActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) and for some reason it doesn't have margins around it. See the image:

[image: dialog without margin]

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 //These are just some setters in the company code
 MyApplication.setActivity(this); 
 setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String action = intent.getAction();
 if(action != null && action.compareTo(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) == 0){
     mHasContent = true;
     mContentUri = intent.getData();
 }else{
     mHasContent = false;
 }
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

 initViews();

 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 builder.setTitle("title");
 builder.setMessage("message");
 builder.create().show();
}
```

I have no idea what is causes the problem, the dialog is showing correctly at other places in my code.
(I have tried to put it into onResume and it's not working eather. I want to show it only when the activity created, that's why I am trying to use onCreate.)

Can my custom AppTheme cause the problem? If you think so I attach my relevant part of my styles.xml:

```
...
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
...
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Toolbar</item>

    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimationTransition</item>
    ...
</style>
...
```

I have tried to create a new project and put all the upper code in it (styles.xml and all the others) and I cannot reproduce the bug. What else can cause the problem?

Where can be the problem? Can anyone help?

I also have an application class with overrided onCreate() function and tried remove those function calls also but nothing changed. Is there other places in android which can impact this behaviour? I don't know the whole code, because it's a company app, so maybe some other overriden method or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed this line from the activity in the manifest file and it solved my problem:

```
android:theme="@style/SplashScreen"
```

I don't know what caused it, so if anybody can explain it to me I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

remove this line `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

Comment: Thx, I will try it tomorrow, but if I want my Activity to be full screen than how should I do that?

Comment: <activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>  add this theme in your manifest file and remove  setTheme(R.style.AppTheme) this line

Comment: I have tried, but I need to set my theme to this,  because it's company app, and we need all the stuff defined there :(. Its not even start without them... Do you think the in the theme?

Answer (score 0):

**//Declare dialog globaly**

> AlertDialog dialog = null;

**//In Actvity Call the function to show Dialog**

> dialogShow();

**//define function outside onCreate()**

void dialogShow() {

```
    AlertDialog dialog = null;

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.education_dialoge_add_language, null);

    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
    dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();

    dialog.show();


}
```

Comment: I'm sorry maybe my question was not clear but I need to call dialog.show() in the onCreate() function, and you are suggesting to place it somewhere else, if I'm right... :(